# Fill a std::vector<double> with a constant value

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stdvector, c++03

My code has to run on several platforms (Linux, Mac, Windows) and architectures (32/64-bits) with several compilers (GCC, MSVC, Intel). In a bottleneck piece of code, I have an already allocated `std::vector<double> x` with a size > 0. What is the best way to fill it with a given constant value `c` ?

My first approach is a loop:

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
  x[i] = c;
```

The loop can also be done with iterators:

```
for(std::vector<double>::iterator it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it)
  *it = c;
```

I also can use the assignment function given by the class `std::vector` and be confident in the fact that there is no reallocation if the size is the same (I hope):

```
x.assign(x.size(), c);
```

Is there a standard way to do that very efficiently ? (I can't test on all the possible configurations, I need a standard or *good-feeling-from-experience* response).

*Note 1: I don't want a solution using asm*

*Note 2: I don't use C++11 for compatibility reasons*

Comment: @眠りネロク: my vector is already allocated. Assignment of a new vector could be fastest ?

Comment: That would be fast if you could use C++11 move semantics. Otherwise, std::fill is the solution.

Comment: I believe construction and supplying with a value will be the fastest way if you're able to do so.

Comment: Sounds weird that mere initialization of an array causes a bottleneck. This would mean that you are performing little extra operations, i.e. few of the elements are actually in use. Maybe a sparse data structure would be a better fit then. Can you tell more about the use of this array ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: the bottleneck is not the initialization. But I have this fill in a piece of code called very often. The context is a wrapper using blas/lapack libraries.

Comment: @DeiDei: unfortunately, I have to be compatible with gcc 4.1.2.

Comment: The fastest way would be to use some intrinsic, such as `_mm512_store_pd`. Note that use of intrinsics does not involve writing asm.

Comment: @Caduchon: if this is not the bottleneck, then optimizing it will give little return. "It is called very often" is an unsufficient argument if other, more costly operations, are called as often.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : that's true. I'm just wondering if I can do faster for each line of this bottleneck. When a code has to run for days on hundreds cores, every little 0,1% is good to gain. ;-)

Comment: @Caduchon Is the constant known in advance? Then you can allocate another vector and swap it on your critical path.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can [use `std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) to fill the whole vector

```
 std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), c);
```

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to the `assign` solution.

Comment: In this case, I prefer a dedicated function (ie in the class `std::vector` itself), theoretically more efficient than a function using more general iterators (ie which are not random access iterators).

Comment: @Caduchon: Note that `std::fill` is a template. There can be a specialization for `std::vector::iterator` (takes a bit of trickery, but not an unusual amount for a Standard Library implementation).

Comment: @Caduchon - Note that `vector::assign` also has to handle the case where the size of the vector changes. So `std::fill` contains less code -> good feeling.

Answer (score 6):

Alternative is to use the vector's [constructor overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that accepts two elements, one is size (count of elements, since on pre-C++11 compiler), the other is the element to fill it with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    const double c = 123.45;
    std::vector<double> v(100, c);
    for (std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: the vector is already allocated and *move assignment* is not possible (pre C++11)

Comment: I explicitly mentioned I can't use C++11.

Comment: @Caduchon I have updated the answer to comply with the C++03 standard.